# Is it possible to switch the user logged in to desktop environment via the terminal?

Tags: terminal, login, desktop

Is there any possibility to login as a different user while changing also the environment (or how do you say the wallpaper, shortcuts,...) via terminal command like `su`, `ssh` or `login`?

Like when you click switch user in the up right corner where your name is and then you log in to a different account.

By environment I mean the thing you see when you boot up the computer and normally login through the login screen. You have your wallpaper, toolbar etc.

So I just want to open terminal in my adam's environment and type `login --change-enviroment john`, rather than clicking adam in the up right corner, logging off and logging in like john

Comment: I am not sure if I follow your question correctly. Each and every user has their own environment set up.

Comment: Yes, but su ssh or login won't change it, they change only the "beginning of the line" in terminal

Comment: Are you referring to an X GUI login System?

Comment: Hmm I want to switch user also graphically, not only in terminal

Comment: But via a terminal command :D

Comment: The only thing I can think of is the X GUI login system, but that is a GUI log in server. Im not sure if this is something your looking for since I never used it..

Comment: Any answer that there is likely will depend on exactly what desktop environment is being used - Gnome? KDE? XFCE? LXDE? Something else?

Comment: You need to [edit your question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/140582/edit) for it needs to contain your desktop environment, nor the display manager.

Answer (score 3):

If you use `lightdm` display manager ([man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/lightdm.1.html)), you can use `dm-tool` ([man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/dm-tool.1.html)) to switch to another user:

```
dm-tool switch-to-user USERNAME
```

Answer (score 0):

You can run multiple X sessions on different VTs and toggle between them.  VTs (virtual terminal) are the non-GUI consoles you can access via, e.g. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Alt</kbd> <kbd>F-#</kbd>, where # is from 1-6.  Your current X session already occupies one, so if F-1 doesn't work, try F-2, etc.

The console will have a login prompt (if you use a graphical login, that may be what you get instead -- I don't so I'm not sure).  You can now login as whatever user you like.  To start a new X session: `startx`.

You can now toggle between the two X sessions via the VTs they are running on.  If it's not obvious, cycle through F 1-6 with ctrl-alt.  You should be able to find both desktops.

Comment: interesting. But it says that startx command is not defined. Can this be controlled by a python script? Like `subprocess.call("chvt 2")` and then `subprocess.call("credentials for the account")`. Also, I need to log out the first user, so if I run pkill (can I when I do not know root password?) it will unfortunately log out the second user on VT, too, or not?

Comment: Try `xinit`.  If you want to actually switch users (log out and in again) but the normal method is too hard for you, your issue is a [corner case](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corner_case) -- i.e., you are looking for functionality few or no people could want, so no one has bothered to implement it.  Either you hack your desktop, the login system, etc. and write the code yourself, or just deal with it.

Comment: Ok, I thought that linux must have command for everything, so this basic action was implemented as a simple command. I googled, but I didn't find anything, so I posted it here.

Comment: Part of the issue is the "switch user" widget is implemented as part of a particular *desktop environment*, of which there is a heterogeneous collection (GNOME, KDE, etc) or *display manager* (the GUI login) of which there is also a heterogeneous collection.  The people who wrote the particular widget you are referring to probably could have written a command line version, but did not bother because they did not think it worth the effort. Since these things are open source, the pattern usually is that features like this get implemented when someone comes along who...

Comment: ... 1) *Can* implement it, 2) *Wants* to implement it.  The fact that no one has indicates, again, that it's a bit of a corner case.  There's really an endless list of things that could be described as a "basic action" that could be "implemented as a simple command".  There's a much shorter list of people with the time, know-how, and desire to do all the work.  Because of that, you often have to go with the flow of what is vs. what is not.